# Where does this equality come from? complex numbers rewritten

Tags: complex-numbers

http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ComplexSequenceSeriesMod.html

See example 4.2. in above. They have $z_n = (1+i)^n$ and then they've rewritten that to a familiar $a_n+ib_n$ form ... where did it come from?

$z_n = \sqrt{2}^ncos(n\pi/4) + i\sqrt{2}sin(n\pi/4) $.....

Comment: The basic idea is that $(re^{it})^n = r^n e^{int}$, then use what you know about $e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from De Moivre's identity:
$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta.\tag{1} $$
By plugging in $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ we have:
$$ (1+i) = \sqrt{2}\cdot e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\tag{2} $$
then:
$$ (1+i)^n = 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot e^{\frac{\pi i n}{4}} = 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\cos\frac{\pi n}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi n}{4}\right).\tag{3}$$

Comment: Yes, of course, seems obvious now. Haven't worked with complex numbers in months, so had forgotten about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$
1+i = \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{1/\sqrt{2}} 
$$
using Euler identity
$$
\mathrm{e}^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x
$$
we can rewrite the above as
$$
1+i = \frac{1}{1/\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = \sqrt{2}\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}
$$
can you extrapolate to
$$
(1+i)^n=?
$$
ps you will also need the identity
$$
\left(\mathrm{e}^{ix}\right)^n = \mathrm{e}^{inx} = \cos nx + i\sin nx
$$